# Order lists in list based on values from other list

Tags: python, list

I want to sort lists in a list based on values from another list. In the example the 5th order should be placed before  0 and 1 because the due date is earlier.

I already tried for loops and other sorting methods but the list in the list is not an integer, which makes ik too hard for me. Therefore I have no idea to solve the following:

```
orders = [[0, 1, 5], [2, 3 ,4]]
##due date for each order
duedates = [5000, 5000, 4500, 3000, 3000, 2750]

expected output: [[5,0,1], [4,3,2]]
```

Comment: Can you explain how are you reaching to expected output?

Comment: I got it based on other methods, but I don't have other input that can be used to solve this.

Comment: You have two lists which are inputs and you have one output..in plain english what logic are you expecting from folks here so that they can get you the expected output

Comment: That the method is able to order a list in a list based on the due dates. In this example: duedate[0] = 5000, duedate[1] = 5000 and duedate[5]=2750. Therefore 5 should be before 0 and 1 in the list. The same holds for order 4 and 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for order in orders:
    orders_due = [duedates[i] for i in order]
    sorted_order = sorted(zip(order, orders_due), key=lambda x:x[1])
    print([i for (i,j) in sorted_order])
```

Comment: Have you considered using a dictionary instead here? The order-numbers would be a good key, while their due-dates would be their values

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> orders = np.array([[0, 1, 5], [2, 3 ,4]])
>>> duedates = np.array([5000, 5000, 4500, 3000, 3000, 2750])
>>> duedates = duedates.reshape(orders.shape)
>>> for i, j in zip(orders, duedates):
...   print([x for __, x in sorted(zip(j, i))])
...
[5, 0, 1]
[4, 2, 3]
```

Comment: This only works for two instances, in reality the lists are longer.

Comment: what do you mean by longer? did you try this solution with your longer list